# Backward Converting SQL Databases

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

Does anyone know of any free tools that can assist in converting an `SQL2005` database back to `SQL2000` format?  I know that you can script all the objects and then do a dump of the data, but this is a lot of work to do manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviewing some other related questions I just found Microsoft's [Database Publishing Wizard](http://www.codeplex.com/sqlhost/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Database%20Publishing%20Wizard).  It does most of what I need, although I have used nVarChar(max) in a couple of places and it simply fails to handle those cases and bombs out without generating anything.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using DTS to transfer the data across? It should be independant of the version.